# What is the ID at the end of the Enterprise SOAP service end point URL?

Tags: soap-api, soap, wsdl, enterprise-wsdl

Is that the Organization Id at the end of SOAP service end point URL? I have checked the organization Id in my salesforce account and this Id did not match with it. Please suggest.

https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/31.0/**0DF90000000DHQR**

Comment: This [Obscure Salesforce object key prefixes](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html) page has "0DF" listed as being an object of type "VersionSet" though I have no idea what one of those is...

Comment: Where did you get that serverUrl from? Mine *always* end in the corresponding OrgId, which has the 00D keyprefix rather than 0DF

Comment: @DanielBallinger i got it from enterprise WSDL

Comment: I agree with @dacology. The [VersionSet](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#0DF) ID "encodes your package version selections when the enterprise WSDL was generated." It mostly applies to the Enterprise WSDL.

Answer (score 8):

The ID at the end is the PackageVersion identifier, this is primarily used in the Partner API WSDL and can be configured on the API WSDL download page (setup->Develop->API) before you generate the WSDL. Even if you have no use for this feature a default ID is generated for backward compatibility.

However, [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_package_versions.htm) probably describe this feature better.