# Are the enterprise WSDL endpoints for Sandbox & Production the same (now)?

Tags: sandbox-refresh, enterprise-wsdl

We have built a .NET app that uses our Enterprise WSDL to pull data from Salesforce , and we use a dedicated development sandbox for ongoing development.

Previously, looking at the WSDLs generated from the two orgs, in addition to the SOAP endpoints starting w/ login.salesforce.com vs. test.salesforce.com, the Id at the end, following the API version number, also used to be different between the two.  I don't know what that Id refers to - it's not the Org Id, or I wouldn't be asking the question ... probably.

I just refreshed that dev sandbox and generated new WSDLs (Production/refreshed sandbox) and the endpoints are identical.  Aside from the 'test' vs. 'login', does that last ID being the same matter anymore?  (That dev team doesn't like to 'just try stuff out' w/o evidence -- engineers...)

Thanks!

Comment: Note: after generating them, the WSDL endpoints are exactly the same, just to be clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50148/what-is-the-id-at-the-end-of-the-enterprise-soap-service-end-point-url

Comment: WSDL describes state of an org. If you have 2 identical orgs -- wsdl are same. As long as you do modification (new field etc), and regenerate wsdl -- it will be different

Comment: I think you are talking about the Authentication URL. Once you call the login method, it will give you the service URL. I am sure the service URL will be different for production and Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

The ID at the end of the Enterprise WSDL URL is the [VersionSet](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#0DF) ID.

> https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/39.0/**0DF1000000000001**

It encodes the managed package version selections when the enterprise WSDL was generated.

For example, the enterprise WSDL might include components that came from managed packages. Salesforce needs to know which version of the managed package that definition came from to keep everything consistent.

It's likely that they used do differ before the refresh as the Enterprise WSDL was retrieved from both the Sandbox and Production independently and an VersionSet was created for each. Now that the sandbox has been refreshed from production it has access to the same VersionSet. 
You can probably confirm this by looking at the [pod identifier](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1663/102) in the 4th and 5th characters of the ID.

See also:

- [Package Version Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_package_versions.htm)